# delay asked for $_SESSION['message']

Tags: php, refresh, delay

I would like a success message to disappear after 3 seconds.

This is my PHP code:

```php
if(!empty($_SESSION['message'])){
    echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"> '.$_SESSION['message'].'</div>';
    $_SESSION['message'] = "";
}
```

Comment: javascript will be the only want to change content after being delivered to a browser, unless you want to have the entire page reloaded from the server.

Comment: @Sammitch thank you for pointing my mis-read out! +1 for javascript